# Whether to go for SharePoint List or Custom SQL Database

Tags: sharepoint-server, list, database, sharepoint-list

I currently have a project to create a database for storing the details of past projects we have done for customers.  However, the data set is relatively small (less than 500) and the data is mostly there to be referenced, not to run any significant calculations.

The company already utilizes SharePoint a lot, so I was wondering if it was really necessary to create a true database.  It would be much simpler on the interface side to use a `SharePoint List`, which could be exported to an `Excel` file if any manipulation needs to be done.

Does this sound like something a SharePoint list can effectively do? Or would it be a much safer route to just set up a database?

Answer (score 3):

Based on your description, you don't have a complex ERD, it just one table to archive your project.

So It recommended creating a **SharePoint list** instead of building a new database then develops UI forms to add, edit, delete and update your project date from scratch. I think it will waste your time.Meanwhile, it doesn't provide a list OOTB capability like:

- Add attachments to projects.
- Tracking your changes (Auditing/Versioning)
- Enable Alerts on new item added or changed or deleted.
- Export to Excel.
- Manage List / Item Permission.
- Search.
- Create views like Gantt view ...etc